# Having trouble representing null sets within Mathematica

Tags: sets

I am having trouble writing the Mathematica code to prove this answer. I was able to derive the answers but through trial and error, ideally I want to derive them through examination of correct code.

```
subsetQ[A_, B_] := Module[{i},
Catch[Do[If[! MemberQ[B, i], Throw[False]], {i, A}]; Throw[True]]]

S1 = Subsets[Subsets[{}]]

MemberQ[S1, {}]
MemberQ[S1, {{}}]
MemberQ[S1, {{{}}}]
subsetQ[S1, {{}, {{{}}} }]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You are more likely to obtain help, if your question shows that you have tried to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: Look up `Subsets[]` as well.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and apologies if my first question is not great. I looked over the Subsets[] documentation but still cannot figure out where I am causing error.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `MemberQ`, you should use the built-in `SubsetQ` for your testing:

```
S1 = Subsets[Subsets[{}]]  (* {{}, {{}}} *)

SubsetQ[S1, {}]            (* True  *)
SubsetQ[S1, {{}}]          (* True  *)
SubsetQ[S1, {{{}}}]        (* True  *)
SubsetQ[S1, {{}, {{{}}}}]  (* False *)
```

---

The documentation explains that `SubsetQ` tests for non-strict subsets, and also yields `True` if its arguments are equivalent. Notice a few differences in behavior between `SubsetQ` and `MemberQ`:

```
list = {a, b, c};

SubsetQ[list, {a, b, c}]  (* True  *)
MemberQ[list, {a, b, c}]  (* False *)

SubsetQ[list, {}]         (* True  *)
MemberQ[list, {}]         (* False *)
```